# Vagrant up command gives executable not found in %PATH% error

Tags: windows, powershell, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have installed vagrant and successfully added vagrant ubuntu box. But on running "vagrant up" command from the project directory, I got this error :

> The executable "powershell" vagrant is trying to run was not found in
>   the %Path% variable.This is an error.Please verify this software is
>   installed and on path.

I also installed Putty client and configured it.

Note: "vagrant init" command works fine and it created a vagrant file in a directory.
Vagrant Version: 1.9.7

VagrantFile contains

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial32"
end
```

Path added to  environment variable : C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin

Comment: can you add your Vagrantfile to the question ?

Comment: I have added vagrant file contents

Comment: And the content of your `Path` environment variable looks like...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add this line to your Path variable, and vagrant start work.

%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

Comment: I had to restart my PC afterwords for `vagrant up` to work.

Answer (score 0):

powershell command not found in your machine.

run powershell command in your machine and check it works fine.

Expected results should be:

*

```
C:\Users\navkuma>powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
PS C:\Users\navkuma>
```

*